# How to pass argument to Class-based Middleware

Tags: typegraphql

I have custom class-based middleware like:

```js
@Service()
export class MyMiddleware implements MiddlewareInterface<Context> {
  constructor(private readonly service: Service) {}

  async use({ info, context }: ResolverData<Context>, next: NextFn) {
    // this.service.doSomeDbLogicHere()
    return next();
  }
}


@UseMiddleware(MyMiddleware)
@Mutation(() => User)
public async createuser() {}
```

I wonder how I can pass custom static values to my middleware, but still have other objects injected via DI.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a function that accepts a static value and return a middleware class.